# Navigation from one component to another component without reloading both the component in Angular 6

Tags: angular6

I have a web application developed using `Angular`.

This is the layout of my web applicaton
[image: This is the layout of my web application]

I have  filters in `filterComponent` and products are displayed in `productsComponent`, On applying the filters in `filterComponent` the products should get updated in `productsComponent` with only refreshing `productsComponent`, In my case both are getting refreshed.

filterComponent.ts

```
if (isChecked) { 
    this.router.navigateByUrl(/home , { skipLocationChange: true });
    setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate([/products, id])); 
}else (!isChecked){
    this.router.navigateByUrl(/home , { skipLocationChange: true });
    setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate([/products, id]));
}
```